# How do I get a new folder to function as an isolated url

Tags: html, hosting

For example - I added /slots and put all of the contents of the website there but it is showing as a directory tree not as the functioning website.

http://sharedsquared.org/slots/

I have done this before successfully, I thought I just added the folder to the directory and it worked.

Comment: It appears as if your site is missing the necessary asp.net handlers.  Make sure that your site has an application pool configured and that the correct version of .net is running for the pool..  In addition, the site appears to be an attempt at asp.net mvc, in which case, you may or may not be missing your compiled code (including routes, etc).

Comment: http://sharedsquared.org/slots/ changed the file name and now the shell is showing - I will do what you suggested to see if the content shows up

Comment: now the css is showing - still can't get the js to pass through http://sharedsquared.org/slots/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your CSS and JS code are not loading.  In Chrome, open developer tools, and see the Javascript console. You're getting 3 404 errors. Your application is in a folder /slots, change the path to your css and js files to:

```
/slots/Content/reset.css  
/slots/Content/slots.css  
/slots/scripts/slots.js
```

or:

```
./Content/reset.css  
./Content/slots.css  
./scripts/slots.js
```

-Jim